# sp_blitz warns me about a heap (that only have 1 row)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, clustered-index, sp-blitz, heap-table

I have just inherrited a "new" SQL Server, and I've run sp_blitz on it.

SP_Blitz warns me about a heap that is being actively queried. The table have just 1 row in it. It is a settings table, so no more rows will ever arrive.

Will adding a Clustered Index gain me anything (except one less row/nag in sp_blitz)?

Comment: I don't think it will, except rid you of that "nag".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can guarantee that the table will only ever have one row, then no, not really, but...

I mean, can you?

If you didn't need multiple rows, why build a table?

And even this philosophical discussion took you more time than just putting a clustered index on it and guaranteeing that you won't have problems with it in the future. ;-)

Comment: @BrentOzare; You are right, I cannot guarantee just one row. But if I add a column (like ID Integer Identity(1,1), then the systems using the database may fall apart. So I've added a clustered key on a random column (that happend to be a tinyint), to stop the nagging.  Thank you for your help.